# what's the difference between those two similar __init__ definitions in python?

Tags: python, init, python-3.9, python-class

what's the difference between

1)

```
def __init__(self): pass
```

and

2)

```
def __init__(self) -> None: pass
```

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In second one, you [annotated](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) the method and explicitly said that the return value of the `__init__` method should be `None`.

Every function/method in Python will implicitly return `None` if you don't have any return statement in the body. It is necessary for `__init__` to return `None`, otherwise you will get the error `TypeError: __init__() should return None,` in instantiation.

Annotation is optional and won't throw an error if you put different value from the specified one:

```py
def fn() -> str:
    return 10

print(fn())  # 10
```

But returning None is a must for `__init__`.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        return 10

obj = A()  # TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'int'
```

Comment: Worth noting that `mypy` (by default) ignores unannotated functions. Adding the return type is the simplest way to annotate the method so that `mypy` doesn't ignore it.